# Change the text of a JLabel with the source of a MouseListener

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a java component for my sudoku project. This component represents a sudoku box that can have two states: a digit or candidates (I use a CardLayout). So far, all works. I am now trying to add some MouseListener on my Labels. When I click on a candidate, I would like to change the value of the state with a simple number, then change the display (cardlayout.show (...)). The problem here is that the source of the event seems to be detected, but the change is not done ... Here is my code (Problem in CaseComponent > createController > candidate[i].addMouseListener():

```
    package sudoku;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CaseComponent extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String CANDIDATES = "candidate";
    private static final String DIGIT = "digit";
    private GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraint;
    private JLabel[] candidates;
    private JLabel digit;

    public CaseComponent(Color caseColor){
        super();
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        setBackground(caseColor);
        createView();
        placeComponents();
        createController();
    }

    private void createView() {
        gridBagConstraint = new GridBagConstraints();
        candidates = new JLabel[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidates[i] = new JLabel(""+(i + 1));
        }
        digit = new JLabel();
    }

    private void placeComponents() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3)); {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                JPanel q = new JPanel(); {
                    q.add(candidates[i]);
                }
                q.setOpaque(false);
                p.add(q);  
            }
        }
        p.setOpaque(false);
        add(p, DIGIT);

        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); {
            p.add(digit, gridBagConstraint);
            p.setOpaque(false);
        }
        add(p, CANDIDATES);
    }

    private void createController() {
        digit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    candidateDisplay();
                }
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidates[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    JLabel source = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                        System.out.println("IN");
                        digitDisplay();
                        digit.setText(source.getText());
                   }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void digitDisplay() {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) getLayout();
        cl.show(this, DIGIT);
    }

    private void candidateDisplay() {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) getLayout();
        cl.show(this, CANDIDATES);
    }
   }

package sudoku;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Sudoku {

    // ATTRIBUTS
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private Timer timer;
    private JButton pauseButton;
    private JButton resumeButton;
    private JButton penaltyButton;
    private JLabel chronoInfo;
    private Chronometer chrono;

    public Sudoku() {
        createModel();
        createView();
        placeComponents();
        createController();
    }

    // COMMANDES

    /**
     * Rend l'application visible au centre de l'écran.
     */
    public void display() {
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // OUTILS

    private void createModel() {
        chrono = new Chronometer();
    }

    private void createView() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Sudoku");

        resumeButton = new JButton("Reprendre");
        resumeButton.setEnabled(false);

        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");

        penaltyButton = new JButton("Penalité");

        chronoInfo = new JLabel("00:00");
    }

    private void placeComponents() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(); {
            p.add(resumeButton);
            p.add(pauseButton);
            p.add(penaltyButton);
        }
        mainFrame.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        p = new JPanel(); {
            p.add(chronoInfo);
        }
        mainFrame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        p = new JPanel(); {
            JPanel q = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3)); {
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    Color caseColor = i % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GRAY;
                    JPanel r = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3)); {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                            r.add(new CaseComponent(caseColor));
                        }
                    }
                    r.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
                    q.add(r);
                }
            }
            q.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
            p.add(q);
        }
        mainFrame.add(p);

    }

    private void createController() {
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final int delay = 1000;
        timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chrono.increment();
                chronoInfo.setText(chrono.toString());
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        resumeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
                chrono.setPaused(false);
            }
        });

        pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                chrono.setPaused(true);
            }
        });

        penaltyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chrono.penalty();
                chronoInfo.setText(chrono.toString());
            }
        });

        chrono.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {     
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                resumeButton.setEnabled(chrono.isPaused());
                pauseButton.setEnabled(!chrono.isPaused());
            }
        });
    }

    // POINT D'ENTREE

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Sudoku().display();
            }
        });
    }

}




package sudoku;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class Chronometer {

    // ATTRIBUTS
    private static final int MAX_SECONDS = 60;
    private final EventListenerList listeners;
    private final ChangeEvent changeEvent;
    private int seconds;
    private int minutes;
    private boolean paused;

    // CONSTRUCTEUR

    public Chronometer() {
        listeners = new EventListenerList();
        changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        paused = false;
    }

    // REQUETES

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

    public ChangeListener[] getChangeListeners() {
        return listeners.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
    }

    // COMMANDES

    public void setSeconds(int s) {
        seconds = s;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int m) {
        minutes = m;
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean b) {
        paused = b;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    public void increment() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds == MAX_SECONDS) {
           seconds = 0;
           minutes++;
        }
    }

    public void penalty() {
        seconds += 10;
        if (seconds >= MAX_SECONDS) {
            minutes++;
            seconds -= MAX_SECONDS; 
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            return;
        }
        listeners.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            return;
        }
        listeners.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }

    // OUTILS

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeListener[] listnrs = getChangeListeners();
        for (ChangeListener lst : listnrs) {
            lst.stateChanged(changeEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

I thank you in advance !

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case there is no `main(..)` method, so at least the C requirement of MCVE or the SC of SSCCE is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that looks like a nice program! I took a quick look and I believe I found the problem. In your `placeComponents` method you swapped the candidates and digit keys of your layout. I also remove unnecessary brackets.

```
private void placeComponents() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JPanel q = new JPanel(); {
            q.add(candidates[i]);
        }
        q.setOpaque(false);
        p.add(q);  
    }

    p.setOpaque(false);
    add(p, CANDIDATES); // was DIGIT

    p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); {
        p.add(digit, gridBagConstraint);
        p.setOpaque(false);
    }
    add(p, DIGIT); // was CANDIDATES
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The mistake was so stupid ...

Comment: Pleasure! In my experience the longer you look for a mistake, the stupider it is.